# How to switch between background images when hovering css only?

Tags: html, css, hover, background-image

i have two images of text. one with regular text and the other with the same text but with glow effect.
the thing is i want the glow image to **replace** the regular one while hover.
but instead the glow image appears in **addition** to the regular one. 
please help!!
thanx in advance
here is the code... the **background-image** attribute is in a comment block because the regular text image is defined as the img **src** int the html file

```
#groundPlainLink
{
height:56px;
width: 170px;
margin-left:476px;
float:left;
/*background-image:url("../images/txt_menu_ground_plane_pc.png");*/
}
#groundPlainLink:hover
{
background-image: url("../images/txt_menu_ground_plane_glow_pc.png"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears in addition, because the IMG element renders above the background image.  Why not just use CSS, and skip the IMG element?

Comment: what do you mean? BTW the img is inside a link (<a><img/></a>>)

Comment: Right, the image is inside `a#groundPlainLink`, right?  You're doubling up the graphic file, because both the `IMG` and the CSS background-image are showing on top of each other.

Comment: upvoted this answer because its the only one that isn't a thoughtless "fix".

Comment: Aw, thinking is overrated ;)

Comment: either you didnt get me or i didnt get you guys. there is no real text... the image itself is an image of text. so, in the html file i dont have a value between the <a></a>... so the hovering  doesnt realy work if i dont use the img attribute

Comment: Right.  There's no reason to have BOTH an `img` element, and use CSS backgrounds for the same graphic

Comment: thats why the background-image is in a comment block... i dont use it in the css

Comment: But you do on hover, which is when it doubles up.  I'm saying remove the `IMG` tag, set the #groundPlainLink's display to block, and uncomment that out in the CSS.

Comment: OK, but what do i need to do with the fact that there is no text written between the <a></a> tags? the hover doesnt work...

Comment: That's okay.  Did you set the `<a></a>` CSS display to "block"?

Comment: no. i did now but nothing happens. how do i need to set the hover? 
a:hover #groundPlainLink ??

Comment: You don't have to change that. `#groundPlainLink:hover` is fine.

Comment: it doesnt work... i have edited the question.. add the html part

Comment: There *should* be text here.  Think of user's who *can't* see images (the blind, bots, users with images turned off to save bandwidth, etc.).  Either the image is content (eg. a diagram, photograph, etc.) and should be an embedded image, or the image is purely decorative and probably should be a background.  Either way, the document needs to make sense with no styles or images.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you couldn't use a background image at all (see: [image replacement techniques](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/).  You *can* use text-shadow to get a glowing effect on text (ask Google, you'll get 100s of results).

Answer (score 1):

You have to hide the image on hover.

```
#groundPlainLink img:hover { opacity:0; }
```

However, as mentioned above, it'd be easier and simpler to remove the img and rely on background images for this.

EDIT: Or, style the  element instead of the div element, then put text inside the link with a `font-size:0`. That'd do what you're looking for and still be good for screen readers/accessibility/SEO.

Answer (score 0):

a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/jd23mcnx/

html

```
<a class="image-link">
    <img class="image-default" src="http://i.imgur.com/c0lfxLU.png">
    <img class="image-hover" src="http://i.imgur.com/yfNIfVR.jpg">    
</a>
```

css

```
.image-link {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
}

.image-link img {
    width: 500px;    height: 300px;
}

.image-hover {
    display: none;
}

.image-link:hover .image-default {
    displaY: none;
}

.image-link:hover .image-hover {
    display: block;
}
```